# Can I free a vassal imprisonned by another?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

So, here is the situation. When my heir turned 16, I gave him a small county for him to gain prestige. I then noticed he had a pretty useful duchy claim, that quickly pressed, and won. He is now Jarl with only a county outside his *de jure* duchy. Obviously, the original owner of the duchy (not the one I declared war to, a previous one) want it back, and claim it from my son, who end up in his donjon.

Now, losing the duchy is not that bad, but it has been a few years, and he is still imprisoned. Is there any way for me, the liege of both, to force the Jarl to free my son? Paying the ransom in his place, transfer to my prisons, anything? The only way I can think of is to give money to my son until he can pay the ransom himself, but currently the coffers of the realm are empty...

Comment: Great, just a minute after I ask this question, I died, and now I am still stuck in prison with my jailer not wanting me to pay a ransom since I have a claim on his titles...

Comment: As you found out, the answer is basically nope if the jailer doesn't want them out (the send them money to ransom themselves usually works otherwise though). Especially annoying when its one of your vassals jailing your relatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you state, you can offer the imprisoned enough gold for them to allow them to extract themselves from the prison.

Additionally you can open up diplomacy with the imprisoning party and ask to ransom prisoner, which again, will cost you.